# Создание online бота

Tags: бот

Какие языки программирования и web разработки вы порекомендуете для создания бота для букмекерской конторы, который бы сам делал ставки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам лично писал похожего бота на IronPython, и был очень доволен и скоростью и возмоностью на ходу менять его код. Также работаю в компании у которой пару десятков ботов написанных на c#. Еще советую использовать для обработки полученных результатов MS SQL Server Analysis Services. Сам его использовал очень удобно. Составляет достаточно правдоподобные прогнозы и хорошо коррелирует данные

Answer (score 0):

На любом языке программирования, которым Вы в совершенстве владеете.

Answer (score 0):

Тут все просто. Берите любой язык, который вам удобен. Но необходимо учесть скорость работы вашего кода, наличие библиотек для работы с биржей и тд. Одно из важнейших требований в этой сфере - именно скорость работы с удаленным сервером. Если вы будете медленно анализировать данные и также медленно реагировать на них, вас обставят другие боты.